# Why does an XML declaration starts with "<?xml" instead of "<!xml"?

Tags: xml, declaration

I thought XML is an application of SGML, and that the default syntax for an SGML declaration starts with `"<!"` delimiter.

Based on that understanding, I'm not clear how `"<?"` comes about.

Would someone please cxplain? Thank you.

Comment: "Why" questions are difficult to answer. It depends whether you mean (a) "as a matter of historical record, do the minutes record why the committee made this decision?" or (b) "can you think of any good reason why a rational person would think this is a good idea?" They're not the same thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<!` begins a DOCTYPE declaration, and `<?` begins a processing instruction. The `<?xml` processing instruction is specified by the standard to indicate that what follows is XML, indicate the version of XML and the text encoding. It has no relationship to the actual structure of the document, which is something the DOCTYPE declaration would. I'm not sure why the DOCTYPE declaration is specified differently than a processing instruction, but a lot (maybe most) XML documents these days have their structure defined by XML schema or RelaxNG instead, and only a DTD can be referenced from the DOCTYPE. There are other ways to use processing instructions; mostly they were introduced to provide vendors with a side entrance for their own features. Probably the second most common use is for linking to XSLT or CSS stylesheets.

XML was originally conceived as a simplified subset of SGML, but since then it has become much more different. It wouldn't really be fair to say XML "is" SGML anymore in any sense, just that they are related by history and genealogy.

Comment: Danielle, thank you very much for the useful explanation. In particular, I greatly appreciate your reference to the term processing instruction. I've found the following two useful links in learning more about it: 

http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-8.htm#PI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction

Comment: I'd say that `DOCTYPE` declarations and XML declarations are quite different things. It's not strange that they are specified differently.

Comment: Daniel: Sorry for the mispelling of your name above. :(

Comment: @mzjn - my point is just that it's interesting that there are two out-of-band mechanisms, one general and one special-purpose, where there could be one instead. I'm sure there are reasons.